# how to convert multi index data to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a list like this.

```
result =  [
{'Global': {'NewConfirmed': 100282, 'TotalConfirmed': 1162857, 'NewDeaths': 5658, 'TotalDeaths': 63263, 'NewRecovered': 15405, 'TotalRecovered': 230845}},
{'Global': {'NewConfirmed': 106598, 'TotalConfirmed': 1252421, 'NewDeaths': 5972, 'TotalDeaths': 67572, 'NewRecovered': 11066, 'TotalRecovered': 241599}}
]
```

I want to convert this data into dataframe as below.

```
   NewConfirmed  TotalConfirmed  NewDeaths  TotalDeaths  NewRecovered  TotalRecovered
0        100282         1162857       5658        63263         15405          230845
1        106598         1252421       5972        67572         11066          241599
```

tried many possibilites, but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use list comprehension for select by `Global` with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x['Global'] for x in result])
print (df)
   NewConfirmed  TotalConfirmed  NewDeaths  TotalDeaths  NewRecovered  \
0        100282         1162857       5658        63263         15405   
1        106598         1252421       5972        67572         11066   

   TotalRecovered  
0          230845  
1          241599
```

If more keys in outer dictionaries use [`json.json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = json_normalize(result)
print (df)
   Global.NewConfirmed  Global.TotalConfirmed  Global.NewDeaths  \
0               100282                1162857              5658   
1               106598                1252421              5972   

   Global.TotalDeaths  Global.NewRecovered  Global.TotalRecovered  
0               63263                15405                 230845  
1               67572                11066                 241599
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. the second option i did get it, however, the header had key= global added to each filed which i was not looking for.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: But why is that when we use a for loop instead of list comprehension, it throws error like
**raise ValueError("If using all scalar values, you must pass an index")
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index** ?
This is why i was not able to obtain desired result.

Comment: @VijayaBhaskar - then is possible use `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('Global.','')` or `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.').str[1]`

Comment: @VijayaBhaskar - Is possible edit question with your loop solution?